# upperCase the first element of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, splice

The error shows "*AssertionError: expected '   NEVER GIVE UP' to deeply equal ' NEVER  GIVE UP '*"
and I can't figure out why blank in the beginning of a string is ignored. Here is my code:

```
function letterCapitalize(str) {
  if (str === '') {
    return ''
  }
  let string = '' //array to string
  let word = str.split(' ')
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] !== '') {
      string = string + word[i][0].toUpperCase() + word[i].slice(1, word[i].length) + ' '
    } else if (word[i] === '') {
      string = ' ' + string
    }
  }
  return string.slice(0, string.length - 1)
}
```

The console log examples include:

```
let output1 = letterCapitalize('hello world');
console.log(output1); // "Hello World"
let output2 = letterCapitalize('javascript  is sexy ');
console.log(output2); // "Javascript  Is Sexy "
```

Comment: Your test seems to want a space in the beginning and one at the end.

Comment: i am not quiet sure which line you are referring to;

Comment: In your `else if`, you are appending a space to the beginning of your (whole) string. You should add it to the end of your string. (Like you do in the `if`.)

Comment: Show us the code for the test case please. Your test seems to be requiring something else other than capitalization.

Comment: @Ivar I am afraid that the test result still remains to be " AssertionError: expected '   NEVER GIVE UP' to deeply equal ' NEVER  GIVE UP ' ". 
Issue is that the double space after "NEVER" does not appear. perhaps rewrite using array?

Comment: @EmilyScone You changed `string = ' ' + string` to `string = string + ' '`? [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/rs1hv06x/)?

Answer (score 0):

Your test seems to want a space at the end, try this if you really want to capitalize the string, or share your test case code so I can have a look.

```
const capitalize = str => {
  if (!str) return "";
  return str
    .split(" ")
    .map(el => el[0].toUpperCase() + el.slice(1))
    .join(" ");
}
```

Comment: 1. It returns as a string type.
2. returns empty string when empty string is given
3. returns "         " when "         " is given 
4.returns "You Can Do It" when 'you can DO it' is given
5. returns ' NEVER  GIVE UP ' when ' nEVER  gIVE uP ' is given
6. returns 'You Have A Idea' when 'you have a idea' is given.

3,5 are the ones that shows error.
the error code of 3 is 
AssertionError: expected '' to equal '    '
and 5 is 
5. AssertionError: expected 'NEVER GIVE UP' to deeply equal ' NEVER  GIVE UP '

Comment: Aaaah ok, now I understand.

Comment: You're not supposed to remove any spaces. No 5 shows an error because your function removes a space from the end.

Comment: I think I can keep space in the end by adding ' ' as I did on the if. however, I can't figure out why the double space after never disappears on my code and how to keep them.